# How can we implement a modal dialog that comes from right and stick to right like bottom sheet dialog?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

I have been using bottom sheet dialog of google material design in our android application. Bottom sheet is implemented in google material design library for android. In the same lines, Is there any library that provides Modal side sheet of material design which comes from right.(https://material.io/design/components/sheets-side.html#modal-side-sheet)?

Comment: It may be a hack but I used DrawerLayout to solve this problem by locking the gestures to open and close drawer layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using `DrawerLayout`. This may be a hack but it is working as i expected. Like navigation drawer I have defined `DrawerLayout` to right of the Activity layout and put my fragment in it. And I have locked the gestures of the `DrawerLayout` using `setDrawerLockMode()`. Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Just add below CSS it will work fine

```
.mdc-drawer--modal, .mdc-drawer--modal{
  left: initial;
  right: 0;
}
.mdc-drawer--animate, .mdc-drawer--animate{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.mdc-drawer--opening, .mdc-drawer--opening{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
}
.mdc-drawer--closing, .mdc-drawer--closing{
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      transform: translateX(100%);
}
```